# ASP.NET MVC: Minifying without Bundling

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a lot of JS files and every one of them is tightly coupled with specific view. I want to minify every of these files but I must create new bundle for every file. Is it possible to minify in some way JS files but without creating bundles?

Comment: You should use other tools, like `Web Developer Tools` for visual studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bundler both bundles and minifies. You can't just minify with it. If you just want to minify then you'll need a post-build hook to call out to something like grunt or ant to take care of that for you, or certain Visual Studio extensions like [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) can be setup to auto-generate minimized versions of your scripts and CSS on save.

Also, it is possible to create bundles on the fly, for what it's worth:

```
@{ BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/foo").Include("~/Scripts/foo.js")); }
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/foo")
}
```

Comment: Yay for creating bundles programmatically. Bundle scripts that are common across all pages in your Layout.cshtml, and then bundle those specific to each page in each view *.cshtml